# Understanding the electoral college

Tags: united-states, election, electoral-college

I understand that the electoral college makes the race more fair by allowing people in small states to have more of a voice.
But, doesn't it take away the voice of people in large states? Right now, it seems from our system, that the only votes that count in the US Presidential election, are the ones cast by people in Florida, Wisconsin, and Pennsylvania. Everyone else may as well not vote.
How is this a fair system?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how the electoral college works. "Everyone else may as well not vote" -if the only voters were FL, PA, WI and all voted for the same candidate, that would only account for 59 of the 270 electoral college votes to win.

Comment: @BobE You are right. I don't literally mean everyone else may as well not vote. What I mean is that for most states it is extremely easy to predict who will win. There are just a handful of states that actually need to vote in order for us to know which candidate wins that state.